# Why did the movie version(s) of Dune have Paul Atreides making it rain?

Tags: movie, dune, powers

I've watched David Lynch's Dune, the 3-hour cut (complete with expository animation sequence) and overall I think it holds up pretty well aside from the strong homophobic bent.

However, one of the scenes that bothers me, in fact, the one bothering me the most, is the part of the final scene **where Paul makes it rain on Arrakis**

Who chose to take this specific diversion from the original novel, and why?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? It's because [HE *IS* THE KWISATZ HADERACH](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B8-eiBqri0U)!!!

Comment: Fun fact: That creepy little girl is a very young [Alicia Witt](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001860/) making her big screen debut.

Comment: @Richard - I need to bleach my brain....

Comment: Why? Because why wouldn't the messiah of the fremen finally make it rain on Arrakis?

Comment: @user66079: Umm, because 1. Messiah's are myths and 2. Because he just wouldn't? i.e. this belief is not suggested in the books; and what are all the sietches for then?

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like to see before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum: You wrote it was very difficult to figure out why, so even though I upvoted you, I still don't know why this happened.

Comment: Now I have to ask... where'd you find the 3-hour cut? I'm trying to find a longer version myself.

Comment: @Omegacron: [Well...](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IdTellYouButThenIdHaveToKillYou).

Answer (score 10):

The concept of the rains coming at the end seems to have crept in somewhere between the [6th](http://www.duneinfo.com/Content/files/dune_script_6th_draft.pdf) and [7th](http://www.lynchnet.com/dune/dunescript.html) version of the script.

In the 6th Draft, the film ends with a closeup of Paul's eye, followed by this scene;

[image]

Precisely one year later, the script entered its final revision and this scene was inserted;

> **284.    EXT. ARRAKEEN PALACE - DUSK**
>
> Paul opens his mouth and issues an ever increasing wind.  Lightning
>     and thunder begin.  Clouds begin to form over the Palace.  In the
>     half-light of dusk, thousands of Fremen watch the sky.  Giant golden
>     lights are illuminated and their rays shoot far into the sky
>     illuminating the growing clouds.  Five tremendous bolts of lightning
>     suddenly unleash a downpour of RAIN ON ARRAKIS.  The Fremen stand
>     awestruck as they are drenched with water falling from the sky.

The '**who?**' of "who came up with the idea?" is pretty easy. The script was written by David Lynch.

The **"why?"** of "why the heck did they do this" is much harder to pin down. Although I personally suspect that this was intended to portray the words at the end of the Dune novel

> "The Fremen have the word of Muad'Dib," Paul said. **"There will be
>   flowing water here open to the sky and green oases rich with good
>   things.**

---

As to why this decision (to have it rain) was ultimately taken, the very best answer I can give is [Lynch's own words](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lZKcW9OGoU)

> "**this film was my one big failure...it was a nightmare...an absolute
>   nightmare...stupid...awful...**"

Comment: Wow. Didn't know Lynch felt so strongly about the movie.

Comment: He completely disowned the TV edit. It was released under the pseudonym Alan Smithee; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Smithee

Comment: I would say the "why" is probably because making rain and implying that the freemen will become free farmers is a more "nice" finale that Paul Atreides'freemen launching their jihad across the galaxy.

Comment: @Sjuan76 - I've seen some speculation that he did it on purpose in order to kill off any possibility that he'd get stuck doing a sequel.

Comment: Lynch was singing a somewhat [different tune](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvCeLzC2sNs) back in 1985.

Comment: @einpoklum - I think it's fair to say that he regretted making it.

Comment: Yes, but then - the rain-on-Arrakis thing is something he did beforehand. Before he regretted things, I would think.

Comment: The interesting thing is that Frank Herbert was personally involved in the film, and had a massive problem with this ending. That would imply either that Lynch and Herbert had a falling out, or that Lynch did it behind his back. Herbert had quite the rant about this film in the foreword to his short-story anthology *Eye*. Herbert, unfortunately, never wrote anything else about it, and I haven't heard Lynch describing any converstions with Herbert either.

Comment: It's unfortunate Lynch feels that way. It's a pretty enjoyable movie and not a bad adaptation of the book.

Comment: @DCShannon says "*It's a pretty enjoyable movie and not a bad adaptation of the book.*".  I remember watching the late-night premier of this film with an audience packed with Dune and science fiction fans.  None of them would have agreed with that sentence.  Once people got over the initial shock of how bad it really was, the rest of the film was filled with bursts of laughter from one ridiculous scene to the next.  Seeing it as a badly made comedy was the only way to avoid walking out.

Comment: @RayButterworth - I liked it. It was a pretty good attempt to film a book that is basically unfilmable

Answer (score -2):

It is established that the planet can only support spice production because it is dry.

Paul says to the Fremen that they must destroy all spice production on Arrakis.

By making it rain, Paul has accomplished the objective he declared.

By inserting this event into the (1984) movie, it provides a logical ending - Paul learns his destiny, seeks a goal, and by movie's end, he's done it. This makes the movie a self-contained story.

Compare to Star Wars (1977). The very first movie ends with the destruction of the Death Star - a nice neat happy ending which doesn't call for a sequel. Obviously, its commercial success demanded sequels. Empire Strikes Back (1980) ends almost abruptly because it is a given that another installment is to come. Return of the Jedi (1983) again ends with a happy ending to properly close out the trilogy (no further installments contemplated at the time).

Consider also Back to the Future. The first movie was written as a stand alone, despite the hook ending (and the "To Be Continued" which was added to the home video release). The second movie truly ends in mid-story with Doc in the old west and Marty in the 1950s because parts 2 & 3 were shot together.

The studio probably anticipated that Dune would not do well at the box office, and may have wanted to close the door on the possibility of anyone pitching for sequel, hence the nice tidy (rain)bow on the story.

Comment: Your're just guessing, though, right? Also I don't find it reasonable within the story arc.

Comment: @einpoklum Speculation yes, but not without justification. It's exactly the sort of thing a studio would do, and such things are always motivated by either profit or politics.